# Fullpage.js - can't remove focus from input in Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js for a website. I have a few ordinary sections, one with overflow scrolling and the last that contains form with text input.

Expected behavior when clicking on the input: it gains focus, keyboard appears, then when clicking outside of it, input loses focus.

Reality: after clicking outside of the input nothing happens, it doesn't lose focus. If hide keyboard, then click outside, even on another section, it appears again and I can't figure out why.

Can someone help?

The issue occurs only in Android

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    verticalCentered: false,
    scrollOverflow: true,
    scrollOverflowOptions: {
      scrollbars: false,
    },

  });
});
```

jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p4behjvs/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. The problem was in iscroll5 plugin. Adding `preventDefault: false` to `scrollOverflowOptions` fixed the issue

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    verticalCentered: false,
    scrollOverflow: true,
    scrollOverflowOptions: {
        scrollbars: false,
        preventDefault: false
    },

});
```